# Is there a way on MacOS that allows the user to move the mouse in straight lines while holding a short key?

Tags: mouse

I'm looking for a way to achieve the same effect as the following utility for Windows but on Mac.

> Using a mouse to draw straight lines on your computer can sometimes be
> a really difficult job. You may be making some drawings and when you
> want to draw a straight line by free hand, it never happens. Drag Lock
> is a light weight utility for Windows that allows users to draw
> straight lines easily by just pressing the Windows button on the
> keyboard while dragging the mouse.

*Source: http://www.blogtechnika.com/draw-straight-lines-easily-using-drag-lock/*